# Como alterar vários registros de uma tabela sql de uma vez?

Tags: php, sql

Imagine um resultado de uma SQL:

```
ID - NOME- MENSAGEM

1 / israel / msg-olamundo
2 / rafael / msg-olamundo
3 / augusto / msg-olamundo
```

Agora eu quero fazer em SQL a mesma coisa q o str_replace faria no php tirar de todos registros de uma x a palavra "msg-".

**Pesquisando encontrei a resposta e queria colocar aqui para ajudar a galera é muito fácil!**

Answer (score 4):

```
update tabela
   set mensagem = REPLACE(mensagem, 'msg-', 'NOVO TEXTO AQUI OU DEIXAR VAZIO PARA APAGAR') 
 where `mensagem` LIKE '%msg-%'
```

Comment: Rapaz, obrigado por compartilhar, salvou aqui...